# Windows 7 git-ftp install/usage

Tags: windows-7, git-ftp

I'm trying to install git-ftp onto a **windows 7 box**. I'm currently developing code, committing to a git repo from my local machine, I then have to ftp the changes across to a dev server . I've searched for ages on where/how to install git-ftp but with minimal/no luck (if it wasn't for bad luck I'd have no luck at all!!)

Can anybody tell me **where/how to install git-ftp?** or at least point me to a site that provides comprehensive step-by-step instructions (many of the sites I've found are confusing make assumptions and don't offer simple instructions) 
I have cloned git-ftp into the git/bin folder however the command 'git ftp push' is not recognized.

Any help generally would be massively appreciated particularly on **where to clone/install the git-ftp folder** and then on how to use the commands.

Thx
AndyM

Comment: https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/blob/master/INSTALL.md#windows

Answer (score 1):

I found this [git-ftp installation and configuration](http://www.codingsips.com/install-configure-git-ftp-windows/) very easy and I feel it is most secure way of repo to server deployment